# Phonegap SQLite Plugin vs build-in functionality?

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova, size

I need to work with a database which can be **>20MB.**

I read a lot about the size Limit of 5 MB and how the `SQLite Plugin` would
solve this issue.
https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin

I wrote a little test filling a table with dummy data, using the build in `Phonegap` functionality. Turns out (on `iOS`) I can easily create a database with 20MB without warnings.

It is stored under `AppData/Library/WebKit/LocalStorage/file_0/0000000000000001.db`

So what is the real difference between the mentioned `Plugin` and `Phonegap 3.1` database functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the limit only applies to Mobile Safari and not to a UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the link [sqlite.org](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) and it says under **Maximum Database Size** as shown:

> The maximum size of a database file is 2147483646 pages. At the
>   maximum page size of 65536 bytes, this translates into a maximum
>   database size of approximately 1.4e+14 bytes (140 terabytes, or 128
>   tebibytes, or 140,000 gigabytes or 128,000 gibibytes).

The third party sqlite plugin you mentioned has [these features](http://brodyspark.blogspot.in/2012/12/cordovaphonegap-sqlite-plugins-offer.html) over built in sqlite (as their claim, you can check it). And you don't need to worry about db size limit in your case since **5MB limit is about `Web SQL API`** not for built in sqlite support of phonegap.

Comment: I know what the max size is. But does phonegap withouth the plugin open a native sqlite db which has no size limits or do I need the plugin mentioned above?

Comment: no need of any plugin.. u refer this doc:http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: Ok. And what is the purpose of this plugin when there is already decent database support?

Comment: They are claiming these are (http://brodyspark.blogspot.in/2012/12/cordovaphonegap-sqlite-plugins-offer.html) their advantages over built in db support..

Answer (score 0):

- You are using the WebSQL-Database under iOS. The WebSQL-Database is limited to 50 MB ([see here](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)).
- The 5 MB you read about is the limit of the ([localstorage API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute)).
- The Phonegap SQLLite-Plugin provides a database with no limits (except the storage cap of the device itself).